# Is there anything wrong with using a ton of xibs in a simple app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a rather simple app. The entire app mostly consists of one window with 4 toolbar tabs on it.

I'm an organization freak with code so I try to have a ton of small code files instead of one or two large ones.

I currently have 5 views. One for the window itself. Then four for, one for each tab. My question is, is there anything wrong with having that many xibs? Are there any performance decreases or caveats in that I need to watch out for?

**Edit**

This is an application for Mac OS X not iOS.

Comment: Why don't you use storyboards? http://www.pearltrees.com/#/N-fa=3099042&N-u=1_332781&N-p=30679457&N-s=1_3109196&N-f=1_3109196&N-play=1

Comment: I'm not using storyboards because this is an OS X application. Not iOS. Thanks though.

Comment: Of course there are performance decreases. Loading 5 xibs instead of 1 takes longer—if nothing else, you're opening and closing 5x as many files. But who cares? The time taken to load them is most likely unnoticeable in almost any reasonable application. If you want to find out for sure how it affects your application, the obvious answer is to test it and see.

Comment: I agree with abarnert. I would add though that good organization doesn't necessarily mean tons of tiny files. In fact, I'd argue that striving for such a goal will lead to code that's hard to follow. While it's good to avoid huge bloated files (XIBs or source code files), breaking things into too many small pieces is just as likely to lead to code that's hard to follow and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experiments with using multiple XIBs vs a single XIB it does decrease performance very slightly, however the performance drop is small that it isn't even noticeable.